# Task is executed on weekend even not defined in "Edit Trigger"

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I have this very strange behaviour. Even in the "Edit Trigger" form the weekend is not enabled the task is getting executed the whole weekend each hour. I already restarted the server. Nothing helps.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...the task is getting executed the whole weekend each hour.

This is the key.  Notice that within your `Advanced settings`, you have the task configured to `Repeat task every: 1 hour` as well as `for a duration of: Indefinitely`.  In other words, once the task is initially triggered (regardless of the day and time), it will continue to repeat on an hourly basis without end.

Ultimately, you might not need to configure the task to "Repeat" at all.  Within the standard `Settings` it is set to run at 20:05 every weeknight.  Do you need it more often than that single occurrence each weeknight?  If not, simply uncheck the box to disable `Repeat task every:`.  If so, there are additional options regarding the task repeating `for a duration of:`, such as `1 hour` or `12 hours`.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood *Indefinitely*. I thought this is meant for the day. I changed "for a duration of:" to "23 hours" and now the task stops on Friday @2300.

Comment: I like to say that "nobody was born with a keyboard in their hands," so it's a good learning experience for all of us.  Glad to hear that everything is now working properly!